# Cross compile boost failed during linking (Ubuntu compiled for raspberry pi)

Tags: c++, boost, cmake, raspberry-pi3, cross-compiling

I am trying to cross compile a c++ project on my ubuntu to run in raspberry pi. However, for some reason I cannot get my make file to work.

I have done few things.

1. I have arm environment setup that I can cross compile simple code (like hello world) on my pc and run in raspberry pi.
2. I have compiled boost with arm's gcc and g++, with methods found here: https://github.com/Yadoms/yadoms/wiki/Cross-compile-for-raspberry-PI

Basically is

```
nano ~/user-config.jam
using gcc : arm : arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ ;

 ./b2 --with-atomic --with-chrono --with-date_time --with-filesystem --with-regex --with-serialization --with-thread --with-system --no-samples --no-tests toolset=gcc-arm link=static cxxflags=-fPIC
```

Yet, it always failed during linking

The sample I used is here:

```
#include <wiringPi.h>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#include <iostream>

#include <string>
int main (void)
{
  boost::filesystem::create_directory("testFolder");
  wiringPiSetup() ;
  pinMode(0, OUTPUT) ;
  for(;;)
  {
    digitalWrite (0, HIGH) ; delay (500) ;
    digitalWrite (0,  LOW) ; delay (500) ;
  }

 std::cout<<"hello world"<<std::endl;
  return 0 ;
}
```

**I have tested the wiringPi lib, it is working fine**

And the CMakeLists.txt is

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)
project(ExoController)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR arm)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++11 -Wall -pthread -lwiringPi -o3") #you can set with add_definitions("-Wall -std=c+11, etc")

set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON)

set(Boost_INCLUDE_DIR /home/lowlimb/rpi-kernel/boost_1_71_0)
set(Boost_LIBRARY_DIR /home/lowlimb/rpi-kernel/boost_1_71_0/stage/lib)


set(CMAKE_SYSROOT /home/lowlimb/rpi-kernel/tools/arm-bcm2708/arm-rpi-4.9.3-linux-gnueabihf/arm-linux-gnueabihf/sysroot)
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER /home/lowlimb/rpi-kernel/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER /home/lowlimb/rpi-kernel/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++)


# Search for programs only in the build host directories
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)

# Search for libraries and headers only in the target directories
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)



set(Include_DIR include)
find_package(Boost 1.71.0 COMPONENTS serialization date_time filesystem REQUIRED)
if(NOT Boost_FOUND)
message(FATAL_ERROR "boost cannot be found")
endif()


#set(Eigen_INCLUDE_DIR /home/pi/Lib/eigen-eigen-323c052e1731)
#wiringPi library libwiringPi.so
set (WPI_PATH /home/lowlimb/rpi-kernel/WiringPi/wiringPi)



# Actually find the wiringPi library object
find_library(WPI_LIB wiringPi HINTS ${WPI_PATH} NO_CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH)
# Alert the user if we do not find it
if(NOT WPI_LIB)
message(FATAL_ERROR “wiringPi library not found”)
endif()


include_directories(
    ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR}
    ${WPI_PATH}
)



link_directories(${WPI_PATH} ${Boost_LIBRARY_DIR})

enable_testing()
add_executable(exo_o main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(exo_o PRIVATE ${WPI_PATH} ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
```

The output I got when make is:

```
CMake Warning at /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:801 (message):
  New Boost version may have incorrect or missing dependencies and imported
  targets
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:907 (_Boost_COMPONENT_DEPENDENCIES)
  /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1558 (_Boost_MISSING_DEPENDENCIES)
  CMakeLists.txt:29 (find_package)


CMake Warning at /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:801 (message):
  New Boost version may have incorrect or missing dependencies and imported
  targets
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:907 (_Boost_COMPONENT_DEPENDENCIES)
  /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1558 (_Boost_MISSING_DEPENDENCIES)
  CMakeLists.txt:29 (find_package)


CMake Warning at /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:801 (message):
  New Boost version may have incorrect or missing dependencies and imported
  targets
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:907 (_Boost_COMPONENT_DEPENDENCIES)
  /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1558 (_Boost_MISSING_DEPENDENCIES)
  CMakeLists.txt:29 (find_package)


CMake Warning at /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:801 (message):
  New Boost version may have incorrect or missing dependencies and imported
  targets
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:907 (_Boost_COMPONENT_DEPENDENCIES)
  /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1558 (_Boost_MISSING_DEPENDENCIES)
  CMakeLists.txt:29 (find_package)


-- Boost version: 1.71.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   serialization
--   date_time
--   filesystem
--   system
-- Configuring done
WARNING: Target "exo_o" requests linking to directory "/home/lowlimb/rpi-kernel/WiringPi/wiringPi".  Targets may link only to libraries.  CMake is dropping the item.
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/lowlimb/Documents/testCode/build
Scanning dependencies of target exo_o
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/exo_o.dir/main.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable exo_o
/home/lowlimb/rpi-kernel/boost_1_71_0/stage/lib/libboost_filesystem.a(operations.o): In function `boost::filesystem::detail::current_path(boost::system::error_code*)':
operations.cpp:(.text+0xbe): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_replace(unsigned int, unsigned int, char const*, unsigned int)'
operations.cpp:(.text+0x140): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_replace(unsigned int, unsigned int, char const*, unsigned int)'
```

(I exclude most of the error since they look like a similar error).
I really don't understand why the make file cannot compile boost correctly. It did find the correct version of boost I used (the original version I installed on this computer is 1.6, only the arm's one is 1.71.0), why it still cannot function properly?

**Additional Info**

I would like to add more info to this question, when I first make the project, something I believe is wrong showed up

```
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 7.4.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 7.4.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
```

However, in my CMakeLists.txt I have already assign a different cxx complier, why it still used /usr/bin/c++?

Comment: Looks like you've compiled boost with the c++11 abi which isn't available in your libstdc++, you probably need to define `_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0` when building boost

Comment: Would you mind give more details about it? I tried
 ./b2 --with-atomic --with-chrono --with-date_time --with-filesystem --with-regex --with-serialization --with-thread --with-system --no-samples --no-tests toolset=gcc-arm link=static cxxflags=-fPIC _GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0

Comment: you'd need `"cxxflags=-fPIC -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0"`

Comment: are you sure, I tried, it cannot work.

Comment: No, I'm just guessing, what do you mean by it cannot work? Do you get an error or does it just not solve the problem? Have you tried deleting the boost build directory before running `b2`?